# error occured when using function sem_init

Tags: c, linux, function, semaphore

I'm using Linux to learn semaphore, trnna test the function sem_init. The code seems simple but the error is unexpected, don't know why. Here's the code and the errors is below the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NITER 1000000

int cnt = 0;
sem_t mutex;
sem_init(&mutex,0,1);

void * Count(void * a)
{
    int i, tmp;
    for(i = 0; i < NITER; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        tmp = cnt;      /* copy the global cnt locally */
        tmp = tmp+1;    /* increment the local copy */
        cnt = tmp;      /* store the local value into the global cnt */ 
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;

    if(pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, Count, NULL))
    {
      printf("\n ERROR creating thread 1");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, Count, NULL))
    {
      printf("\n ERROR creating thread 2");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(pthread_join(tid1, NULL))    /* wait for the thread 1 to finish */
    {
      printf("\n ERROR joining thread");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(pthread_join(tid2, NULL))        /* wait for the thread 2 to finish */
    {
      printf("\n ERROR joining thread");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (cnt < 2 * NITER) 
        printf("\n BOOM! cnt is [%d], should be %d\n", cnt, 2*NITER);
    else
        printf("\n OK! cnt is [%d]\n", cnt);
  
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

my english is bad, if anything is hard to understand please tell me and ill respond you as soon as possible!thx
[image]

Comment: I got it, i should use the function in main function instead of outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare  variables outside the main and the other function which mean that the variable is global .

But to call the function `sem_init(&mutex,0,1);` you should do it from the main  or from another function. In your case , you have to do it in the main.

After moving the sem_init inside the main it compile

```bash
nabil@DESKTOP-8ECTID4:~/stackoverflow$ gcc bad.c -o bad -lpthread
nabil@DESKTOP-8ECTID4:~/stackoverflow$
```